# Simple wild character for mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

new to mod_rewrite. I simply want to make something like this:

```
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On    

# use item php page to show the item
RewriteRule    ^parts/./[.]$    parts/item.php?id=$1    [NC]
```

so when a person types in example.com/parts/anything/anything, the URL will go to

example.com/parts/item.php?id=the2ndanything

From my understanding, the period means any character. Also, I tried to add a + after the period(which should mean as much as anything), but that still didn't work.

by the way, I am on a temporary URL, since I have not changed my previous web host yet, and therefore my actual full URL has a ~ in it. I am hoping this is not an issue for mod_rewriting and therefore being the issue that stops it from working. the .htaccess file is in the root folder with the web sites index.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` does mean *any character*, but you must follow it by `+` (one or more) or `*` (zero or more) and you must capture it in `()` to be used as `$1`.  Use `[^/]+` to match all characters up to but not including `/` to match but not capture the first directory after `parts/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# (.*) captures the second "anything" in $1
RewriteRule ^parts/[^/]+/(.*)$ parts/item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: answer accepted. i know this is the correct way. everything you said makes absolute sense, but i can't seem to get it working. getting 404 from the server.... hmmm :/

Comment: @DaveFes add [R]  to see what it is attempting to redirect to

Comment: redirects to the following: http://66.147.244.97/home8/davidssite/public_html/parts/item.php?id=1

which is giving a 404 code. also i should mention, any parts of this  url(directories or pages) removed, will still throw a 404, so it seems its off at the root from the get-go!

Comment: Add a / before the rewrite parts/index.php. odd and I can't easily diagnose from here.

Comment: just changed hosting let me see what happens and now my IP and site are fully established. no more temp ~ url

Comment: Michael, thanks for patience. Got it working as intended. Thanks a bunch! One day I shall repay :)